# Alternative to Amazon CloudFront for CDN?

Tags: cdn

I've been using CloudFront for a while now but it seems lately my CDN files aren't always loading. I have a number of customers experiencing issues and the only fix is to restart their computer. Annoying for them and me.

Can anyone recommend a better CDN provider that's not too expensive? I'm still small so paying $99 a month is way too expensive for me at this stage.

I've had a look at some reviews on the net but they aren't that helpful. Some are a bit biased and are almost like paid reviews.

Two things I really need is:

1. Ability to serve the files a HTTPS
2. Ability to refresh the files quickly if I make a change (I used Query Strings to do this on CloudFront)

Appreciate your help

Comment: Just an FYI, but query string invalidation doesn't always work, notably because the popular Squid poxy server (by default) won't cache resources with query string parameters.  See : http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet  or https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching

Comment: you may also find [jare.io](http://www.jare.io) useful, a free and instant CDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can checkout [CDNPlanet](http://www.cdnplanet.com/). You will find there a list of some of the most known CDN on the market.

Comment: Thanks @Geoffroy. Have you had any personal experience with any of those CDN's that you'd recommend?

Comment: @BenSinclair [Cachefly](http://www.cachefly.com/) is a pretty good one. I've used it on previous projects and I think they offer everything you asked for.